# Opening Chrome://plugins/ from a hyperlink

Tags: html, google-chrome, local

Since the recent Chrome 21 update, a large number of the flash tools my company uses for its business are now unavailable to Chrome users (thank's to the terribly implemented Pepper plugin). To enable Chrome users to still use our tools we would like to inform them how to disable Pepper Flash and revert to an old Flash plugin stored on their machine.

My query is how do I create a hyperlink on our website that opens the plugins page in a new window? Usually you would enter "Chrome://plugins/" however, when using this in a hyperlink at the moment, nothing is displayed (I understand this may be for security purposes however we really need to make this as simple as possible for users to do.

Comment: Have you try to enable this link from chrome extension? It will work from an extension. As an example you can see this:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iblhmendleblcobcmphbhljgkfgnjoch

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work. We cannot ask our users to install an extension just to open a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in your question, you cannot open chrome://* from an hyperlink due to security reasons.

Another way to do what you want to do would be to make a script that would modify the file %appdata%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

It's a simple JSON file, easy to modify. These are the lines that could interest you in this file:

```
{
 "enabled": true,
 "name": "Shockwave Flash",
 "path": "C:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\21.0.1180.60\\gcswf32.dll",
 "version": "11,2,202,235"
}, {
 "enabled": false,
 "name": "Shockwave Flash",
 "path": "C:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\PepperFlash\\11.2.31.144\\pepflashplayer.dll",
 "version": "11.2.31.144"
```

Comment: Hi J.-B. C. I'm afraid I don't quite follow how to implement the solution you have provided. Could you please provide a bit more detail?

Comment: We tried this but unfortunately it seems that Pepper Flash isn't always shown in the preferences file, even though it shows as an installed extension. And worse, if you do it this way, it seems to keep re-enabling itself. For us, this is a nightmare as it removes core functionality from a key business-critical application.